# Attribute Error (Python PNCC using Spafe) module 'scipy' has no attribute 'fftpack'

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, attributes, extract, speech

I am trying to extract the speech features using Spafe project available here

https://github.com/SuperKogito/spafe/blob/master/examples/features_pncc_example.ipynb.

I have used the PNCC feature extraction program available in the spafe project.

I am getting following error. Please help.

pnccs = scipy.fftpack.dct(V)[:, :num_ceps]
AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'fftpack'

The code is given below.

```
import scipy
from spafe.utils import vis
from spafe.features.pncc import pncc
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav

# init input vars
num_ceps = 13
low_freq = 0
high_freq = 2000
nfilts = 24
nfft = 512
dct_type = 2,
use_energy = False,
lifter = 5
normalize = True

# read wav
(fs, sig) = wav.read("sample.wav")

# compute features
pnccs = pncc(sig=sig,
             fs=fs,
             num_ceps=num_ceps,
             nfilts=nfilts,
             nfft=nfft,
             low_freq=low_freq,
             high_freq=high_freq,
             dct_type=dct_type,
             use_energy=use_energy,
             lifter=lifter,
             normalize=normalize)

# visualize spectogram
vis.spectogram(sig, fs)
# visualize features
vis.visualize_features(pnccs, 'PNCC Index', 'Frame Index')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid `scipy.fftpack`.

> Legacy discrete Fourier transforms (scipy.fftpack)
>
> Warning: This submodule is now considered legacy, new code should use scipy.fft.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/fftpack.html